# Separating web.config sections using configsource in a server farm

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Looking ahead in the likely event we will build a server farm rather than maintaining individual servers etc I am looking into ways to reduce the task required for running an asp.net web application on a server farm.

With regards web.config files, I belive that all the web.configs need to be same on each machine. I assume that in the case where we use the configsource attribute to separate sections into their own files..eg:

```
...
<pages configSource="App_Data\Configuration\pages.xml"/>
...
```

...that all these files also need to be the same. This certainly makes sense but does this work in a server farm? ie using the configSource links or would it be a better practice to have a single web.config in each app on each machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a single web.config for each application and each machine.

Comment: Do you recommend this because it results in only one file to update and keep synched across the servers? Are there any other benefits?

Comment: Accepted as the logical choice.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you mark. The reason that I'd have the configs separated is redundancy. If the files are shared on a network drive you have a single point of failure (for all web servers). There are also a number of security issues with configuration files on a network share. The last reason would be to allow each server different configuration behaviour (if required). Hope that helps.

Kane

Comment: Hi Kane, I would definately not have config files on a share, indeed that would be a single point of failure. I mean I have a web.config in the root of the site and have split some of the sections into their own files (connectionstrings, appsettings, pages(usercontrols) etc. These are just located in the App_Data folder for security. I guess as long as they're the same it should be ok? and if I need to sync the applications and other files in a an automated process, a couple more configs doesnt matter. I cant see how different servers would need different configurations...yet?